# Type inference for nested types in Scala

Tags: scala, type-inference

I want to write a generic class that takes a nested type. The outer type (`I`) has to extend Iterable, and the inner type (`M`) can be anything.

Here is the example I have:

```
// The outer type here is I and the inner type is M
class GenericDistributor[I <: Iterable[M], M] {
  def map(input: I): Unit = {
    input.foreach(item => {
      //do some stuff
    })
  }
}

class IntegerGroup(id: Int, items: Set[Int]) extends Iterable[Int] {
  override def iterator: Iterator[Int] = items.iterator
}

object IntegerGroupDistributor extends GenericDistributor[IntegerGroup, Int]

val integerGroup = new IntegerGroup(1, Set(1,2,3))
IntegerGroupDistributor.map(integerGroup)
```

The problem is that I have to explicitly define the inner type M in the GenericDistributor class which I do not want to.  Is there a way for Scala to automatically infer the inner type given the outer type?

**EDIT**

According to the comment of @Arioch. I tried duck types and that seems to fix my problem but still I feel there should be neater way.

```
class GenericDistributor[I <: {type M; def iterator: Iterator[M]}] {
  def map(input: I): Unit = {
    val it: Iterator[M] = input.iterator
    it.foreach(println)
  }
}

class IntegerGroup(id: Int, items: Set[Int]) extends Iterable[Int] {
  type M = Int
  override def iterator: Iterator[Int] = items.iterator
}

object IntegerGroupDistributor extends GenericDistributor[IntegerGroup]
```

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/duck-typing-scala-structural ?

Comment: Duck types seems to fix my problem but still not sure if I can do that without setting that `type M = Int`

Comment: can you just use straight-forward inheritance? `class GenericDistributor[M] { def map(input: Iterable[M]): Unit = { input.foreach(item => {...` - in other words you never need `I` in your example, you only need `M` everywhere, so why even bother? /// I guess the main trouble for scala is that Iterable is a trait, so you could well have something like `class IntegerGroup(id: Int, items: Set[Int]) extends Iterable[Int] with Iterable[Double] with Iterable[String]`

Comment: Basically that your `type M` is exactly targeting that multiple inheritance problem. You literally tell Scala that of all the thinkable Iterables you only want her to care about Iterable[M==Int] and ignore other Iterables. One other thing to consider maybe would be to use implicits. So your GenericDistributor would be parametrised by M==Int, but your IntegerGroup would have some implicit conversion back to Int, or to Iterable[Int]. But that looks like Goldsberg Machine of a kind.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to use any custom methods of type `I`, your external class need only be parameterized on `M`. The `Iterator[M]` does not needed to be added separately since you already have all you need to define it from `M`.

```
class GenericDistributor[M] {
   type I = Iterable[M]
   def map(input: I): Unit = {
      input.foreach(item => {
         //do some stuff
      })
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem is I might need that I type

Comment: @mehmetgunturkun you would need "I" type - the explicitly named `Iterable`, specific pinned down Iterable of many other Iterables implemented by your class? Or you would need `class IntegerGroup` ?

Comment: Try something like this `class GenericGroup[T](id: T, items: Set[T]) extends Iterable[T] {  type MainIterableType = T; override def iterator: Iterator[T] = items.iterator }` - your main goal is to fix the specific Iterable of many possible ones, so Scala could select at call site the specific main type of many

Answer (score 2):

If you only want a single type parameter there are two options:

(1) State that you do not care about the iterator's type

```
class GenericDistributor[I <: Iterable[_]]
```

(2) Use an implicit to store the inner type

```
class GenericDistributor[I : IterableInfo]
// or (equivalently)
class GenericDistributor[I]()(implicit i: IterableInfo[I])

trait IterableInfo[I] {
  type Element
}

object IterableInfo {
  implicit def forIterable[I <: Iterable[M], M]: IterableInfo[I] { type Element = M } = ...
}
```

The last option allows you to shape your code in a lot of different ways. You could add methods to `IterableInfo`, you could add `type` members, you could add a restriction of `Iterable` to the `I` type parameter.

Comment: It is kind of weird seeing `IterableInfo[I, M]` and `IterableInfo[I]` and `IterableInfo` in the same scope. Are those independent types or the same type with different levels of specialization ? If latter then why option 1 quoted `Iterable[_]` rather than merely `Iterable` ?

Comment: following option 1, if the given class would implement both `Iterable[Int]` and `Iterable[String`, which one be picked by Scala caling `map`? Or how should one specify it at the call-site?

Comment: @Arioch'The You are completely right about the weirdness. I fixed that updated the answer to reflect the problem in my (untested) code.

Comment: @Arioch'The I am not following your comment about option 1. That one states that it does not care what type it is, therefore you could not use that type in any generic method that only knows about `I`, you could only use it in concrete implementations.

Comment: I mean why do you specify `class GenericDistributor[I : IterableInfo]` instead of `class GenericDistributor[I : IterableInfo[_]]` and why cannot you do the same and specify `class GenericDistributor[I <: Iterable]` instead of `class GenericDistributor[I <: Iterable[_]]` ? object-companion is not the type per se, so it is not the one used to specialize type-parametrized generics, right?

Comment: Your answer in many ways repeats my generic suggestions in the top-comments, but I was not able to express them in Scala syntax which you are capable of. So I am asking again about `class AmbivalentGroup(id: Int, items: Set[Int]) extends Iterable[Int] with Iterable[Double] with Iterable[String]` - then following your option 1 I declare `val ag = AmbivalentGroup(...); val gd = class GenericDistributor[AmbivalentGroup](...);` then I call `gd.map(ag);` - and which of 3 `Iterable`s in `ag` would be used by `map` ?  If `map` per se was parametrised I could specify `gd.map[Int](ag);` but it's not

Comment: `Iterable[Int] with Iterable[Double] with Iterable[String]` is not possible in scala

Comment: why? which specs should it violate ?

Comment: @Arioch'The I have no faith in the scala spec stating these types of things. Scala is defined by the compiler implementation which gives you an error if you try something like this: `object Y extends X[String] with X[Int]`